# Attaching image thumbnails from camera or photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, image

I have a static UITableView which on cell that looks like this:

[image]

Getting the Camera and Attach buttons to work was no problem. The user can take a picture or select one from their photo library.

What I want to do 3 things:

1. Take the resulting image from the UIImagePickerController and add a thumbnail below the "Pictures" label.
2. Do 1. for multiple images.
3. Have the option to remove an attached image.

My initial thought is to create a custom UIView that has a UIImageView and a delete button, and create one of these custom views for each image the user attaches and display them in a UICollectionView.

**EDIT:** Another option could be to insert a cell below the "Pictures" cell that contains a UIImageView, and enable editing for those cells so they can be removed.

My question is this: is there a better way of doing this? Are there any online references I should be looking at? I've looked around for a while but haven't been able to find what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a UICollectionView embedded in a UITableViewCell. The cell has a height of 0 to start and only shows when an image is added. Then, images are removed from the collection via UILongPressGesture.